# nlogn vs square root of n , Isn't square root slower?

Tags: big-o

I was doing this quiz on an online course and one question stated;

The function nlogn + √n + 5 may set to belong to
A:  nlogn
B:  √n
C:  n√n

The quiz said the correct answer is A, but isn't square root of n slower? I am new to finding the time complexity of an algorithm and could use an explanation. Or let me know if the answer is wrong.

Comment: in a nutshell, `n*sqrt(n)` > `n*log(n)` > `sqrt(n)` > `log(n)`

Comment: for better understandings, [plot on WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7Bsqrt%28x%29%2C+x+sqrt%28x%29%2C+x*log%28x%29%2C+log%28x%29%7D)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consider `n` to be an extremely large number. For any `n>2`, `n>√n` and `logn>1`. Thus, `nlogn>√n`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct Hierachy is this:

Superlinear`[ n log n]` `>` Linear `[n]` > sub polynomial `[n^(1/a)]`

Where `a: a >= 1.`

Thus `n log n = O(n) = O(sqrt(n))`

N does not need to be an 'Extremely large number" though Big-Oh deals with limits to infinity. In particular, you can set your `n0` as `b+Where b is the base of the logarithm. In this case 10.

Test with `n=11` yourself to find out.

Comment: @Grez kev see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, √n is surely more than logn. ([cf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42038565/632951))

But you're multiplying that logn with n.

n is obviously more than √n.

(If you would multiply √n with n too, then the answer is n√n.)