# Is complexity O(log(n)) equivalent to O(sqrt(n))?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

My professor just taught us that any operation that halves the length of the input has an O(log(n)) complexity as a thumb rule. Why is it not O(sqrt(n)), aren't both of them equivalent?

Comment: Plot the graphs of `log(n)` and `sqrt(n)` up to about `n==1000`, see if you still think they are equivalent, whatever you mean by that.

Comment: log(1) = 0  and sqrt(1) = 1

Comment: Sorry I don't know what I was thinking, all answers are extremely informative though. Thank you

Comment: Is `log(n)` equivalent to `sqrt(n)`? differing only by a constant factor?

Comment: The generic way to check comparative growth of two functions is to take the limit of the ratio of the two functions. If the limiting value is infinity, then numerator is growing faster, and the converse is true if the limiting value is zero. The growth of the functions are comparable if the limiting value is some constant. You might consider checking the response below from 'Sandipan Dey'.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

They are not equivalent: *sqrt(N)* will increase a lot more quickly than *log<sub>2</sub>(N)*. There is no constant *C* so that you would have *sqrt(N) < C.log(N)* for all values of *N* greater than some minimum value.

An easy way to grasp this, is that *log<sub>2</sub>(N)* will be a value close to the number of (binary) digits of *N*, while *sqrt(N)* will be a number that has itself half the number of digits that *N* has. Or, to state that with an equality:

*log<sub>2</sub>(N) = 2log<sub>2</sub>(sqrt(N))*

So you need to take the logarithm(!) of *sqrt(N)* to bring it down to the same order of complexity as *log<sub>2</sub>(N)*.

For example, for a binary number with 11 digits, 0b10000000000 (=2<sup>10</sup>), the square root is 0b100000, but the logarithm is only 10.

Answer (score 39):

Assuming natural logarithms (otherwise just multiply by a constant), we have

`lim {n->inf} log n / sqrt(n) = (inf / inf)`

```
                        =  lim {n->inf} 1/n / 1/(2*sqrt(n)) (by L'Hospital)
                        =  lim {n->inf} 2*sqrt(n)/n
                        =  lim {n->inf} 2/sqrt(n)
                        =  0 < inf
```

Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation for alternative defination of `O(.)` and thereby from above we can say `log n = O(sqrt(n))`,

Also compare the growth of the functions below, `log n` is always upper bounded by `sqrt(n)` for all `n > 0`.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Just compare the two functions:

```
sqrt(n) ---------- log(n)
n^(1/2) ---------- log(n)

Plug in Log
log( n^(1/2) ) --- log( log(n) )
(1/2) log(n) ----- log( log(n) )
```

It is clear that: ***const . log(n) > log(log(n))***

Comment: for better understanding with visualisations, [plot on WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7Bsqrt%28x%29%2C+x+sqrt%28x%29%2C+x*log%28x%29%2C+log%28x%29%7D)

Answer (score 7):

No, It's not equivalent.

@trincot gave one excellent explanation with example in his answer. I'm adding one more point. Your professor taught you that

```
any operation that halves the length of the input has an O(log(n)) complexity
```

It's also true that,

```
any operation that reduces the length of the input by 2/3rd, has a O(log3(n)) complexity
any operation that reduces the length of the input by 3/4th, has a O(log4(n)) complexity
any operation that reduces the length of the input by 4/5th, has a O(log5(n)) complexity
So on ...
```

It's even true for all reduction of lengths of the input by `(B-1)/Bth.` It then has a complexity of `O(logB(n))`

`N:B:` `O(logB(n))` means `B` based logarithm of `n`

Answer (score 5):

One way to approach the problem can be to compare the  rate of growth of O([image: sqrt(n)])
and O( [image: log(n)])

1. [image: derivative of sqrt n]
2. [image]

As n increases we see that (2) is less than (1). When **n = 10,000**  eq--1 equals **0.005** while eq--2 equals **0.0001**

Hence [image: log(n)]  is better as n increases.

Answer (score 3):

No, they are *not* equivalent; you can even prove that

```
   O(n**k) > O(log(n, base))
```

for any `k > 0` and `base > 1` (`k = 1/2` in case of `sqrt`).

When talking on `O(f(n))` we want to investigate the behaviour for *large* `n`, 
*limits* is good means for that. Suppose that both big `O` are equivalent:

```
  O(n**k) = O(log(n, base))
```

which means there's a some finite constant `C` such that

```
  O(n**k) <= C * O(log(n, base))
```

starting from some large enough `n`; put it in other terms (`log(n, base)` is not `0` starting from large `n`, both functions are   continuously differentiable):

```
  lim(n**k/log(n, base)) = C 
  n->+inf
```

To find out the limit's value we can use [L'Hospital's Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html), i.e. take derivatives for numerator and denominator and divide them:

```
  lim(n**k/log(n)) = 

  lim([k*n**(k-1)]/[ln(base)/n]) =

  ln(base) * k * lim(n**k) = +infinity
```

so we can conclude that there's no constant `C` such that `O(n**k) < C*log(n, base)` or in other words

```
 O(n**k) > O(log(n, base))
```

Comment: So are you positing that if matrix multiplication can be done in O(n^2 log n) time, then omega w=2?  As I can see its a sort of contradiction in such case.  You could say w=2.00000000000001 even but it's not 2.  Interesting when a problem is expressed in terms of n^k when it's solution could be n^(k-1)log n

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't. 
When we are dealing with time complexity, we think of input as a very large number. So let's take n = 2^18. Now for sqrt(n) number of operation will be 2^9 and for log(n) it will be equal to 18 (we consider log with base 2 here).  Clearly 2^9 much much greater than 18.
So, we can say that O(log n) is smaller than O(sqrt n).

Answer (score 0):

To prove that `sqrt(n)` grows faster than l`gn(base2)` you can take the limit of the 2nd over the 1st and proves it approaches 0 as n approaches infinity.

```
lim(n—>inf) of (lgn/sqrt(n))
```

Applying L’Hopitals Rule:

```
= lim(n—>inf) of (2/(sqrt(n)*ln2))
```

Since `sqrt(n)` and `ln2` will increase infinitely as `n` increases, and 2 is a constant, this proves

```
lim(n—>inf) of (2/(sqrt(n)*ln2)) = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Use L'Hospital's rule to find this...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).