# Question about time complexity and Master Theorem

Tags: algorithm, master-theorem

I'm quite new to algorithm and I encountered a question that I don't know how to apply Master Theorem:

We have an algorithm `A`, which solves `P` by creating 3 subproblems, each of size `2n/3`, recursively solving each subproblem, and then combining solutions in *`O(nlogn)`* time. Would this algorithm have a better running time than *`O(n)`*? Prove your answer.

What I know here is `a=3`, `b=3/2`, but how can I deal with *`O(nlogn)`*?

Comment: Hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038294/is-complexity-ologn-equivalent-to-osqrtn

Answer (score 2):

Henve, the recursive formula is `T(n) = 3T(2n/3) + O(n\log(n))`. As `f(n) = O(n\log(n)) = O(n^{\log(3)/\log(1.5)}) ~ O(n^{2.7})`, from the master theorem we can say `T(n) = \Theta(n^{2.7})`. 
Therefore, `T(n) = \Omega(n^{2.7})`.