# Time complexity of recursive function dividing the input value by 2/3 everytime

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I know that the time complexity of a recursive function dividing its input by /2 is log n base 2,I have come across some interesting scenarios on

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42038565/8169857

Kindly help me to understand the logic behind the scenarios in the answer regarding the derivation of the formula

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Examples

Answer (score 1):

It's back to the recursion tree. Why for `1/2` is `O(log2(n))`? Because if `n = 2^k`, you should divide `k` times to reach to `1`. Hence, the number of computation is `k = log2(n)` comparison at most. Now suppose it is `(c-1)/c`. Hence, if `n = (c/(c-1))^k`, we need `log_{c/(c-1)}(n)` operations to reach to `1`.

Now as for any constant `c > 1`, `limit log2(n)/log_{c/(c-1)}(n), n \to \infty` is equal to a constant greater than zero, `log_{c/(c-1)}(n) = \Theta(log2(n))`. Indeed, you can say this for any constants `a, b > 1`, `log_a(n) = \Theta(log_b(n))`. Now, the proof is completed.