# what is the n_0 for which log(n)=O(n^1/100)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I know that `log(n)=O(n^1/100)`, according to [Is complexity O(log(n)) equivalent to O(sqrt(n))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038294/is-complexity-ologn-equivalent-to-osqrtn/42038398)
how do you formally show that? you need to find the `n_0` so that for every `n>n_0` it is true that `log(n) < k*n^(1/100)` for some constant `k`, how do you find those `n_0` and `k`?

Comment: Uhm... how do you know `log(n)=O(n^1/100)` ? As written that is a dubious statement at best... Did you mean `O(log(n)) = O(n^1/100) ? That is easier in the sense that O(n^1/100) will always contain O(log(n)) for a suitable constant C. (Depending on how = is defined for O() it is not commutative, so that might explain it)

Comment: @user268396: I guess formally, `O(f)` is defined as a set of functions, so one probably should say `log(n) ∈ O(n^(1/100))`.  But `=` is a pretty common and well-understood abuse of notation, and anyway OP has given the precise statement of what is to be proved.

Comment: Easy way to see: pick n such that log(n) < n^(1/100) which is easy to solve for. Then observe that both functions are monotonous increasing functions for n>0 (the domain of log(n)).

Comment: I don't think that quite does it; in general, two monotone increasing functions can cross each other's graphs arbitrarily many times.

Comment: Right, the missing ingredient here is that one derivative is going to be larger than that of the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Finding an `n_0` such that `log(n_0) < (n_0)^(1/100)`

You don't need to find **the** `n_0`. You just have to find one `n_0` that works. You can just pick an incredibly big `n_0`.

Let `n_0 = 10^1000`. It's a 1 followed by 1000 zeroes. Then:

- `(n_0)^(1/100) = 10^10 = 10000000000`;
- `log(n_0) = log_10(n_0) / log_10(e) = 1000 / log_10(e) < 4000`.

I am assuming `log` meant natural logarithm. But as you can see, binary logarithm, natural logarithm and decimal logarithm only vary by a small constant factor anyway.

So we have found an `n_0` such that `log(n_0) < (n_0)^(1/100)`. Now we need to prove that for all `n > n_0`, `log(n) < n^(1/100)`.

### Proving for all `n > n_0`, `log(n) < n^(1/100)`

To do that, we can prove that the difference `f(n) = n^(1/100) - log(n)` is an increasing function of `n`.

This function is differentiable on the positive reals; its derivative is:

```
f'(n) = 100 / (n^(99/100)) - (1 / n)
f'(n) = (100 n - n^(99/100)) / (n * n ^(99/100))
f'(n) > 99 n / (n * n ^(99/100)) = 99 / (n ^ (99/100))
f'(n) > 0
```

Hence the difference is strictly increasing; since `f(n_0) > 0`, we have `f(n) > f(n_0) > 0` for all `n > n_0`.